# nova instance can not reach metadata server

Tags: metadata, openstack, openstack-neutron

I create a subnet before i create an instance by python script.

```
def subnet_create(self, network_id, **kwargs):
    params = {'name': kwargs.get("name"),
              'cidr': kwargs.get("cidr"),
              'ip_version': 4,
              'enable_dhcp': True}
    body = {'subnet': {'network_id': network_id}}
    body['subnet'].update(params)
    return self.neutron_client.create_subnet(body=body).get("subnet")
```

after that i create an instance by code:

```
compute_srv = self.nova_cli.instance_create(
                                compute_inst["name"],
                                compute_inst["image"],
                                compute_inst["flavor"],
                                key_name=compute_inst["key_name"],
                                user_data=compute_inst["user_data"],
                                security_groups=compute_inst["security_groups"],
                                nics=compute_inst["nics"])
```

the horizon shows  the subnet and the instance was created successfully, but when i open the console page, sometimes the terminal shows that the instance cannot attach to the metadata server:

```
calling 'http://169.254.2169.254/2009-04-04/metadata/instance-id' failed
```

the current instance can not ping the subnet gateway, but instance from other subnet can ping this instance.

This problem is not present every time. some other times it may shows the instance has attached to the metadata server， and the hostname、ip address can set right.

But when i create the subnet manually by horizon,the instances always able to connect the metadata server.

I so confused, and i have stuck here for about a whole week.Does anyone knows why? Thank you very much.

Comment: I solved this question by restart the compute node, but i don't knwo why.